# why compiler says ‘pthread_getthreadid_np’ was not declared in this scope?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I am using Debian stable. I was coding a multithreaded application in C++ and using `g++` compiler and `-lpthread argument` to compile.

But the function `pthread_getthreadid_np()` not works:

> error: ‘pthread_getthreadid_np’ was not declared in this scope

what is causing this error?

Comment: Did you `#include <pthread.h>`?

Comment: Yes included. But not works

Comment: To start with, you do know that the `_np` ending to the function name means Non Portable? That means it may not exist on all systems. Also, after checking [this FreeBSD manual page](http://www.manualpages.de/FreeBSD/FreeBSD-9.0-RELEASE/man3/pthread_getthreadid_np.3.html) you might need to include `<pthread_np.h>`. Of course, being non-portable the header file might not be correct for Debin Linux.

Answer (score 4):

`_np` means "not portable" (or "not Posix"), meaning it's not available on all platforms. This function seems to be specific to BSD, to get a platform-specific integer ID for the calling thread. It doesn't exist on Linux.

Depending on what it's used for, you may or may not be able to use the `pthread_t` handle returned by the portable `pthread_self` function (which is an integer type on Linux), or the numeric thread ID returned by the Linux-specific `gettid` system call. Alternatively, rethink whatever you're doing so you don't need to deal with thread identities.