# Executing threads in 'paralelism'

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I have a range of number (i.e 1~10000).
I need to create `threads` to search for a value X.
Each thread will have your own interval to search for it (i.e 10000/threadNumber).
I guess there is no meaning to make the threads run in sequence.  I'm having problem to make they run concurrently...

My Code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#define limit 10000
#define n_threads 2


void* func1(void* arg)
{
    int i=0, *value = (int *)arg;
//How may I know which thread is running and make the thread search for the right range of values ?
    for(i=1; i<=limit/n_threads; i++)
    {
        if(*value == i){
           //Print the thread ID and the value found.
        }
        else
          //Print the thread ID and the value 0.
    }
    return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    if(argc < 2)
        printf("Please, informe the value you want to search...\n");
    else{
        pthread_t t1, t2;
        int x = atoi(argv[1]);  //Value to search

        pthread_create(&t1, NULL, func1, (void *)(&x));
        pthread_create(&t2, NULL, func1, (void *)(&x));
        pthread_join(t1, NULL);
        pthread_join(t2, NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Problems so far:

- I don't know how to find `thread ID`. (tried with `pthread_self()` but I always get a giant negaative number so I think something is wrong.
- I know that `pthread_create()` creates and initialize the thread, also the `pthread_join` will make my main program to wait for the thread. But Looking into my code it doesn't seems to be runing concurrently.
- How my `threadX` will know from what range of values it's suppose to start searching ? (i.e: If I have 10 threads, I don't think I'll have to create 10 functions o.O ).
- is it possible to make them run concurrently without something like `Mutex` ?

Comment: perhaps this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091000/how-to-get-thread-id-of-a-pthread-in-linux-c-program) can give additional info.

Comment: If you want to pass more than one value (eg. X and the range to search in) to your thread function, you can put them in a structure and pass a pointer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the thread id varies according to your operating system.

See [how to get thread id of a pthread in linux c program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21091000/how-to-get-thread-id-of-a-pthread-in-linux-c-program) as @user3078414 mentioned, and [why compiler says ‘pthread_getthreadid_np’ was not declared in this scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19954890/why-compiler-says-pthread-getthreadid-np-was-not-declared-in-this-scope).

Credits to @Dmitri, an example of passing multiple values to the thread function. The threads run concurrently. Mutexes is a whole other chapter that deals with shared data and how you access it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define limit 10000
#define n_threads 2

struct targs {
  int from;
  int to;
};

void *func1(void *arg) {
  struct targs *args = (struct targs *) arg;
  printf("%d => %d\n", args->from, args->to);
  // free(arg)
  return NULL;
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  struct targs *args;
  pthread_t t1;
  pthread_t t2;

  args = (struct targs *) malloc(sizeof(args));
  args->from = 0;
  args->to = 100;
  pthread_create(&t1, NULL, func1, (void *) args);

  args = (struct targs *) malloc(sizeof(args));
  args->from = 100;
  args->to = 200;
  pthread_create(&t2, NULL, func1, (void *) args);

  pthread_join(t1, NULL);
  pthread_join(t2, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```